# str_replace causing error inside function, yet alone, works okay

Tags: php

I have been stuck on this for quite some time today. I am getting an error pointing to this line:

```
$tplHtml = str_replace('{{TITLE}}', $row['title'], $tplHtml);
```

```
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

So I extracted the entire function this line is in, and put in its own file. It seems to be fine there. Weird.

Can anyone see why this is causing me an error? I just don't know what else to do. The error message is not helping me much. I researched it, and apparently this could be a hundred issues.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

```
<?php
require("functions.php");

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "marketplace";

$items = [];
$results = [];






//----------------------
// DATABASE FUNCTIONS
//----------------------

/*
* Insert Data into database
* @param  string  $tbl      Table name to insert into
* @param  array   $arrData  The array of data to insert
* @return int     $lastId   ID of last inserted record
*/
function saveData($tbl, $arrData){

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "marketplace";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    for ($x = 0; $x <count($arrData); $x++) {

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO items (title, price, location, miles, imgUrl, itemURL) VALUES (";
        $sql = $sql . "'" .$arrData[$x]['title']."',";
        $sql = $sql . "'" .$arrData[$x]['location']."',";
        $sql = $sql . "'" .$arrData[$x]['price']."',";
        $sql = $sql . "'" .$arrData[$x]['miles']."',";
        $sql = $sql . "'" .$arrData[$x]['imgUrl']."',";
        $sql = $sql . "'" .$arrData[$x]['itemURL']."')";

        echo $sql;
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }


    }


    mysqli_close($conn);


}

/*
* Empties a database table
* @param  string  $tbl          Table name to empty
* @return int     $numAffected  Number of rows deleted
*/
function emptyTable($tbl){

}


/*
* Load data from table
* @param  string  $tbl  Table name to read from
* @return array         Array of records
*/
function getData($tbl){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "marketplace";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbl;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($tbl == "items"){
            $items[] = $row;
        }else{
            $results[] = $row;
        }

    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }


    mysqli_close($conn);
    if($tbl=="items"){
        return $items;
    } else {
        return $results;
    }

}

function wipeData($tbl){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "marketplace";



    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE ".$tbl;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    if($result !== FALSE)
    {
        echo("All rows have been deleted.");
        return true;
    }
        else
    {
        echo("No rows have been deleted.");
        return false;
    }

}


function emailResults($diff){


    $div = <<<EOF
    <!-- START LOOP HERE -->
    <div style="background-color: transparent;">
    <div class="block-grid four-up no-stack" style="margin: 0 auto; min-width: 320px; max-width: 650px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; background-color: #ffffff;">
    <div style="border-collapse: collapse; display: table; width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;"><!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:transparent;"><tr><td align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:650px"><tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"><![endif]--> <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="162" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;width:162px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;"><![endif]-->
    <div class="col num3" style="max-width: 320px; min-width: 162px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 162px;">
    <div style="width: 100% !important;"><!-- [if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
    <div style="border: 0px solid transparent; padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;"><!--<![endif]-->
    <div align="center" class="img-container center fixedwidth" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;"><!-- [if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr style="line-height:0px"><td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center"><![endif]--><img align="center" alt="Jeep" border="0" class="center fixedwidth" src="{{IMGURL}}" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; height: auto; width: 100%; max-width: 130px; display: block;" title="Image" width="130" /> <!-- [if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></div>
    <!-- [if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div>
    <!--<![endif]--></div>
    </div>
    <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]></td><td align="center" width="162" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;width:162px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 1px dotted #E8E8E8;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:35px;"><![endif]-->
    <div class="col num3" style="max-width: 320px; min-width: 162px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 161px;">
    <div style="width: 100% !important;"><!-- [if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
    <div style="border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 1px dotted #E8E8E8; padding: 30px 0px 35px 0px;"><!--<![endif]--> <!-- [if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
    <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; line-height: 1.2; padding: 10px 10px 5px 0px;">
    <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; color: #555555; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
    <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: left; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 19px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 16px; color: #2190e3;"><strong>{{TITLE}}</strong></span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- [if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> <!-- [if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
    <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; line-height: 1.2; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;">
    <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; color: #555555; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: left; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 17px; margin: 0;">{{MILES}}<br /><a href="http://www.facebook.com/{{ITEMURL}}">View</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- [if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> <!-- [if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div>
    <!--<![endif]--></div>
    </div>
    <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]></td><td align="center" width="162" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;width:162px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 1px dotted #E8E8E8;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:55px; padding-bottom:5px;"><![endif]-->
    <div class="col num3" style="max-width: 320px; min-width: 162px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 161px;">
    <div style="width: 100% !important;"><!-- [if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
    <div style="border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 1px dotted #E8E8E8; padding: 55px 0px 5px 0px;"><!--<![endif]--> <!-- [if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
    <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; line-height: 1.2; padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;">
    <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; color: #555555; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
    <p style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 24px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 20px;"><strong>{{LOCATION}}</strong></span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- [if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="divider" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; min-width: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
    <td class="divider_inner" style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; min-width: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; padding: 10px;" valign="top">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="divider_content" height="30" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-top: 0px solid transparent; height: 30px; width: 100%;" valign="top" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
    <td height="30" style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top"><span></span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- [if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div>
    <!--<![endif]--></div>
    </div>
    <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]></td><td align="center" width="162" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;width:162px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:55px; padding-bottom:5px;"><![endif]-->
    <div class="col num3" style="max-width: 320px; min-width: 162px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 162px;">
    <div style="width: 100% !important;"><!-- [if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
    <div style="border: 0px solid transparent; padding: 55px 0px 5px 0px;"><!--<![endif]--> <!-- [if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
    <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; line-height: 1.2; padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;">
    <div style="line-height: 1.2; font-size: 12px; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; color: #555555; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
    <p style="line-height: 1.2; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 24px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 20px;"><span style="font-size: 20px;"><strong>{{PRICE}}</strong></span></span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- [if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> <!-- [if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div>
    <!--<![endif]--></div>
    </div>
    <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> <!-- [if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]--></div>
    EOF;

    $tplHtml = "";



        foreach($diff as $row){

            $tplHtml = $tplHtml . $div;
            $tplHtml = str_replace('{{TITLE}}', $row['title'], $tplHtml);
            $tplHtml = str_replace('{{PRICE}}', $row['price'], $tplHtml);
            $tplHtml = str_replace('{{LOCATION}}', $row['location'], $tplHtml);
            $tplHtml = str_replace('{{MILES}}', $row['miles'], $tplHtml);
            $tplHtml = str_replace('{{IMGURL}}', $row['imgUrl'], $tplHtml);
            $tplHtml = str_replace('{{ITEMURL}}', $row['itemURL'], $tplHtml);
        }



    // Load email template into variable
    $email_html = file_get_contents("notify.html");

    // Insert the HTML we just built above, into template
    $email_html = str_replace('{{ITEMS}}', $tplHtml, $email_html);

    $subject = 'New Vehicles Found - MPB';

    $headers = "From: MarketplaceBOT\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@mpb.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "CC: johns@gmail.com.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $message = $email_html;

    $sms = "There are new JEEPS listed. Check your email to see the new Jeeps posted.";

    $to = 'john@gmail.com';

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo 'Your message has been sent.';
    } else {
        echo 'There was a problem sending the email.';
    }

    }  




// LAST SCRAPED RESULTS
$r = getData("results");
//var_dump($r);

// ALL RESULTS
$i = getData("items");


// ARE ARRAYS THE SAME?
$same = is_identical($r,$i);

// GET DIFFERENCE
$diff = difference($r, $i);

// INSERT DIFFERENCE INTO ITEMS
if($same !==1 && count($diff)>0){

    //save diff
    saveData("items",$diff);

    // TODO: Remove any rows in items that are not in results

    // Notify User
    // TODO: 
    emailResults($diff);
    echo "done emailing results";

}

// WIPE OUT RESULTS , READY FOR NEXT SCRAPE
wipeData("results");


?>
```

Comment: This code is run by a cron job and has no user interaction. Am I still vulnerable that way?

Comment: Yes, you are still vulnerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't properly terminate your [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). **That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.**

```
    EOF;
```

doesn't work, it needs to be:

```
EOF;
```